# Laravel FormBuilder validation rules

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation, formbuilder

I have some problems with validation rules.
I want that the second form choice is REQUIRED only if in the first form are selected choice number 1,2 or 3..
Here's what I tried to do:

```
       $this->add('trasporto', 'choice', [
        'label' => 'Trasporto',
        'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group choice-main-wrapper'],
        'choices' => [
            '0' => '',
            '1' => 'Trasporto conto terzi > 1000 m3/anno',
            '2' => 'Trasporto conto terzi tra 500 m3/anno e 1000 m3/anno',
            '3' => 'Trasporto conto terzi < 500 m3/anno',
            '4' => 'Trasporto conto proprio oltre 300 m3/anno',
            '5' => 'Trasporto conto proprio sino a 300 m3/anno',
            '6' => 'Trasporto furgoni conto proprio',
            '7' => 'Grande ﬂotte auto > 300 m3/anno',
            '8' => 'Piccole ﬂotte < 50 m3/anno',
            '9' => 'PMI e artigiano < 4 carte',
        ],
        'choice_options' => [
            'wrapper' => ['class' => 'choice-wrapper'],
            'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label-class'],
        ],
        'expanded' => false,
        'selected' => ['0'],
        'multiple' => false,
        'rules' => 'required',
    ]);

    $this->add('trasportoTerzi', 'choice', [
        'label' => 'Trasporto c/o terzi',
        'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group choice-main-wrapper'],
        'choices' => [
            '1' => 'Trasporto furgoni conto terzi',
            '2' => 'Trasporto persone  BUS',
            '3' => 'Noleggiatori NTL e breve termine',
            '4' => 'Amministrazione pubblica',
            '5' => 'Trasporto furgoni artigianato',
            '6' => 'Altro o non conosciuto',
        ],
        'choice_options' => [
            'wrapper' => ['class' => 'choice-wrapper'],
            'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label-class'],
        ],
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'rules' => 'required_if:trasporto,==,1|required_if:trasporto,==,2|required_if:trasporto,==,3'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (remove "==" symbols):

```
required_if:trasporto,1|trasporto,2|trasporto,3
```